# Background image not showing up (using pseudo selector)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Why is background image not showing up? I tried almost every method from google but I cannot see anything.
please give me a solution.
:(

Code is below.

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="home">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*CSS*

```
.home {
    display:flex;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}

.home::before {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    background:url(https://pixabay.com/photos/workplace-team-business-meeting-1245776/);
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;

    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Because the URL for the background does points to a HTML page, not an image?

Answer (score 1):

Download the image and write into url('...') path to the image OR you need path directly to the image:

https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/09/09/22/workplace-1245776_960_720.jpg

Right click on the image -> View Image

Answer (score 0):

```
.home::before {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    background:url(".home::before {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    background:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/09/09/22/workplace-1245776_960_720.jpg");
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;

    top:0;
    left:0;
});
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;

    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

NOTE: Check if the image is useable. Check license before public using it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your pic because I've tried with another pic, and it works

```
.home {
    display:flex;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
.home::before {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    background:url('https://unsplash.com/photos/O2o1hzDA7iE/download?force=true&w=1920');
    position:absolute;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;

    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```